# How to fix Symfony 3.4 @Route and @Method deprecation

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony-3.4, deprecation-warning

I have a Symfony 3.4 project and I have found below messages in profiler:

1. “Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route” annotation is deprecated since version 5.2. Use “Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route”
2. “Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method” annotation is deprecated since version 5.2. Use “Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route”
3. “sensio_framework_extra.router.annotations” configuration is deprecated since version 5.2. Set it to false and use the “Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route”

I have spent some time on looking for a solution, but found nothing really helpful.
Some findings [here](https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/2062) or [here](https://github.com/symfony/demo/issues/785).

Comment: You didn't specify a question ... what do you want to reach?

Comment: Oh yes. I forgot to add "How to fix ...." I have it in my notepad and forgot to copy and paste. Fixed

Answer (score 13):

Replace this:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;

class UserController
    {
    /**
     * @Route("/users")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public action index()
        {}
```

With this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
class UserController
    {
    /**
     * @Route(path="/users", methods={"GET"})
     */
```

H/T this guy -> https://medium.com/@nebkam/symfony-deprecated-route-and-method-annotations-4d5e1d34556a

Answer (score 11):

Here is a solution I have found. [This post](https://medium.com/@nebkam/symfony-deprecated-route-and-method-annotations-4d5e1d34556a) helped me a lot with a tweak in no. 3
In no. 3 instead of adding config/packages/framework_extra.yaml, I have added that setting to my config.yml.

Comment: I've updated my post to mention your change that applies to Symfony 3.4. Thanks @Strabek !

Answer (score 0):

```
Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route
Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method
```

is deprecated [source](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html#configuration)

```
Use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route
```

[Symfony core annotation use](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html)